# Validation of dialog inside a accordion panel affects the acordion panel functionalty

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a dialog inside an accordion with a command button. If I click on the command button the dialog opens and inside is a input text component. I have made a validation saying, name should not be empty.

The problem I am facing is even though I did not clicke on the command button the validation message for the input text appears, saying that it should not be empty. This appears every time and the application hangs. I have tried setting dynamic="false" but this did not work neither.

I am using prime faces 3.5 and jsf2

```
<p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" id="editSeAccordion" >
    <p:tab id="Edit3" title="myEdit">
        <p:dialog widgetVar="addSAPDialog" id="sapDialog" modal="true" minimizable="false"
            style="position:fixed;" closable="true" position="350,250" maximizable="false" >

            <p:panel style="border:none;background:#F0F0F0;margin-top:-10px;">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="msg.EditService_s}" styleClass="label" />  
                    <p:inputText label="name" styleClass="textfield" 
                        value="#{serviceManagedBean.sapBean.name}" required="true" 
                        requiredMessage="name is compulsary"/>

                </h:panelGrid> 
                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" styleClass="btn-secondary" 
                    style="float:right;margin-top:20px;" onclick="addSAPDialog.hide();"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Ok" styleClass="btn-primary" ajax="true"  
                    actionListener="#{serviceManagedBean.createAddSapPanel}"  
                    oncomplete="handleDialogSubmit(xhr, status, args)"/>

            </p:panel>
        </p:dialog>
```

Comment: You should provide the commandButton that open dialog.

Comment: I have done that.. Dialog opens properly and validation is happening inside a dialog. But I m facing issue when I click on tabs of accordion panel, Even though I did not clicked the command button(After refreshing page or navigating back from some other page to this), validation message appears name should not be empty and page hangs.

Comment: Why you nest dialog inside tab ?

Comment: should I keep the dialog outside the tab?

Comment: of course, you can, i have just debug in primefaces showcase, when you change tab: javax.faces.partial.execute: form:accordion

Comment: javax.faces.partial.execu... form:accordion
javax.faces.partial.rende... form:accordion

Comment: @shreekanth: I just tried to format the code in your question. You are not closing the `p:tab` and you are not closing the `p:accordionPanel`. Is this also in your code?

Comment: @Jens: Yeah I have done that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use separate h:form element for inputs inside the dialog. Because if click accordion tabs the required inputs are validated no matter the partial process or partial render is used.